# ".. давали ей денег" или "... давали ей деньги"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно?

Мы уже давали ей **денег** в этом месяце.

Мы уже давали ей **деньги** в этом месяце.

Answer (score 5):

Зависит от контекста: если деньги на *неопределенные* расходы (сколько-то денег; она постоянно просит денег на пропитание и т. п.), то первый вариант предпочтителен, а если на что-то *конкретное* или по расписанию (деньги, причитающиеся за работу, за квартиру и т. п.), то второй.

Answer (score 3):

ДАТЬ — 1. что (полный охват предмета действием). Дать книгу; Дать ключ от двери. 2. чего (частичный охват предмета действием). Дать денег на дорогу; Дать хлеба. В разговорно-просторечной и диалектной речи могут употребляться в форме родительного падежа также существительные со значением конкретного предмета, если указывается объект временного пользования: Дай шаечки, когда вымоешься (Пом.); Дайте, маменька, платочка пот обтереть (Остр.); Дай ножичка.

Розенталь Управление в русском языке.

Оба варианта возможны. Зависит от контекста.

Answer (score 2):

Если уж говорить **о грамматике**, то желательно указать следующее.

Из словаря:

**ДАТЬ,** св. 1. (кому-чему) кого-что. Передать из рук в руки; вручить. Д. денег на дорогу. Д. завтрак с собой. Д. банку под сметану. Д. сдачу.

**ДАВАТЬ** – форма **несовершенного** вида, для глагола ***дать*** в его первом значении эта форма используется для выражения **многократности** действия.

Формы глагола ***давать***: [https://www.translate.ru/grammar/ru-fr/давать](https://www.translate.ru/grammar/ru-fr/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Соответственно, при анализе ситуации следует учитывать и выбор падежа (винительный или родительный), и значение многократности.

Получится тот вариант, который обозначил Alex_ander

*Мы уже давали ей **денег** в этом месяце.* Родительный падеж. **Неопределенность** (суммы и предназначенности расходов) и **повторяемость.**

*Мы уже давали ей *деньги* в этом месяце.* Винительный падеж. **Определенность** (определенная сумма или конкретность платежа) и **повторяемость**.